# Find object through chained ManyToOne relationships

Tags: mysql, symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to find a group of objects based on a layered relationship. I have 3 entities like so:

Referral --> manyToOne --> Patient --> manyToOne --> Payor

How do I find all referrals a given payor?

I'm using symfony3 with mysql and doctrine. My entities:

```
class Referral
{
    // usual stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Patient")
     */
    private $patient;
}

class Patient
{
    // usual stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Payor")
     */
    private $payor;
}

class Payor
{
    // usual stuff
}
```

Obviously I could make the relationships birectional, for example so I could do something like this in my controller:

```
$patients = $payor->getPatients();
foreach ($patients as $patient) {
    $referrals = $patient->getReferrals();
}
```

And then collect these into an appropriate array, but this seems messy and I'd rather do it all in a single database query in my repository. Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find all referrals for a given payor using a query.

in ReferralRepository

```
public function findReferralsByPayor(Payor $payor)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r');

    $qb
        ->join('BUNDLENAME:Patient', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.id = r.patient')
        ->where('p.payor = :payor')->setParameter('payor', $payor)
        ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```